# How to hide/show UITextView in iOS Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, swift4

```
textView.isHidden = true //false
```

I'm trying to hide/show UITextView by setting isHidden but it doesn't work properly. It does hide the UITextView but it still shows an area where the previous content was. See the image below. The right side is where I'm hiding, the view is hidden as we don't see pink view, but it looks like it still has content area in it. Any idea how to hide UITextView completely including it's content? I did search but couldn't find any solution.

[image]

Comment: Hint: "hidden" does not mean "removed"

Comment: You can use a UIStackView to do so: When the view is hide, then it changes the view arrangements.

Comment: It's just like real life. Suppose you have three spoons in front of you. And you hide the middle spoon. Do the right or left spoons move? No. There is an empty space where the middle spoon was.

Comment: @Moritz that's the Android way. (Gone).

Comment: Yes, there isn't something similar to the android `gone`. You can use a stackView or play with the constraints...

Answer (score 0):

Set those views in single stack so if you hide one view it will automatically arrange its container with remaining elements.

Answer (score -2):

You should change height of textview

Comment: Content will change, height will change. I don't want to restrict it to a height. If it was setting height the I could have already done it. Looks like stackview is the answer as per comments above.